# How do I run Javascript within html code that is in a PHP variable as part of a function

Tags: javascript, php

I am struggling to get the Javascript action going in the "onchange" event in the below example. I have tried all sorts of different syntax, but it does not work.

```
function display(){

    $headingData ='<select name="input" id="input" onchange="$("#frmInput").submit()" >';
        $headingData.='<option value="...." '.$selected.'>Selection1</option>';
        $headingData.='<option value="...." '.$selected.'>Selection2</option>';
    $headingData.='</select>

    return $headingData;
}
```

Comment: Attach the handler properly in Javascript instead of trying to use inline attributes, which is as bad as `eval` and difficult to manage given the required escaping.

Comment: ok, can you give me an example?

Comment: `onchange="$("#frmInput").submit()"` uses two levels of double quotes...
Trying using `&quot;` as an entity within the double quotes, or a backslashed single quotes.

Comment: You need to change `onchange="$("#frmInput").submit()"` to `onchange="$(\'#frmInput\').submit()"`

Comment: yes, that did the trick, please create answer so that I can tick it off, thanks

Comment: so, this turned out to be just a syntax problem, but I'd still be keen to understand what the event handler would look like here?